# Sampling columns in a matrix within R

Tags: r, matrix, sample

I would like to be able to sample a matrix column at random in R.

Let's say I have the matrix

```
x <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)

x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

To sample one column at random, I do

```
y <- x[sample(ncol(x), size = 1)]
```

However, what is returned is not a list of sorted values corresponding to either column 1 or 2 of the matrix x.

Essentially, I would like y to return either column 1 or column 2 at random, exactly as written in the matrix, but I can't seem to understand what's happening here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are working with `matrix`, the indexing should be `row, column` (similar to `data.frame` - but in `data.frame` if we don't specify the `,`, by default it will give the columns as columns are the individual units).  In a matrix, the individual unit is an element.  So, without the `row,column`, it extracts the element based on that position.  To avoid that, use `,`.  One more thing is that when we have a single column/row, it will drop the dimensions as `drop = TRUE` by default for `?Extract`

```
x[,sample(ncol(x), size = 1), drop = FALSE]
```